# Adding <sup> asterisk to placeholder, or a nice way to mark required fields via placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I'm looking for a way to style the asterisk in the placeholder.

Plain text like this in placeholder does not satisfy me:

> Your e-mail*

Note that the placeholder text is variable, so static background will not play the trick

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:after` works but you need to target the placeholder and not the input element...and then you can use `position: absolute;` and `top, left` properties to move your `*` anywhere you want to...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bN3sT/) (Am not sure about other syntax but I've tested on webkit as am using firefox < 17 so if something is failing in any browser please let me know)

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" />
```

CSS

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
   content: '*';
}

:-moz-placeholder:after { /* Firefox 18- */
   content: '*'; 
}

::-moz-placeholder:after {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   content: '*';
}

:-ms-input-placeholder:after {  
   content: '*';
}
```

Comment: You've got two `-moz` declarations, and no unprefixed version. Also: +1.

Comment: @DavidThomas `double` colon replaced the `single-colon` selectors for pseudo-elements in CSS3 to make an explicit distinction between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements so declared both ;) and am not aware of general version for this, if you know feel free to edit my answer :)

Comment: @EugeneKrevenets thank you for notifying, I'll take a look once I get back to work :)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. You can [go here](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) to find any HTML Entity to add to your placeholder. Make sure your head has a meta tag which uses charset UTF-8.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control input-lg formData" placeholder="Your Email&#42;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to keep the asterix in the placeholder as a fallback because this works in Webkit browsers only. So for other browsers your users don't know what field is mandatory.

Then you facing another problem - two asterixes in the placeholder. This can be fixed really easily by javascript.

I wrote an article about this: http://d.pr/1zQu

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way i found was to give the input field a background image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      input.mandatory {
        padding: 2px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        background-image: url("http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002a/asterisk.png");
        background-position: 160px -10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 30%;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input class='mandatory' type='text' placeholder='Username'>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7jnyqos/18/