# Adding asterisk to placeholder in Firefox, -moz-placeholder::before no longer works

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, placeholder

I'm trying to add an asterisk before the placeholders of required inputs. I was using `input::-moz-placeholder:before` which I found on this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878812/adding-sup-asterisk-to-placeholder-or-a-nice-way-to-mark-required-fields-via) and it was working the last time I checked in January. However, it seems that it is no longer supported. Here's what I have going:

```
div.interactFieldRequired {
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder:before  {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
    input::-moz-placeholder:before  {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
    input:-ms-input-placeholder:before  {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
    input::-moz-selection:before  {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
    input[type="text"]:before  {
        content:'* ';
        color: $error-color;
    }
}
```

This is working in every browser except Firefox and IE10. I cannot alter the HTML, although I can use Javascript. However, I'd prefer to do this with scss.

Comment: Perhaps an HTML entity or unicode instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange indeed. I haven't found any reasons why placeholder css support has been removed from Firefox - this applies for Developer Edition too. So if you are OK with JS, you can take advantage of JavaScript `document.getElementsByTagName()` method and loop through this list and concat() each input's placeholder to an asterisk , like so:

```
var asterisk = "* ",
    inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(i=0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
     inputList[i].placeholder = asterisk.concat(inputList[i].placeholder);
}
```

It has a wide support amongst the browsers. I've made an example of that on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh361bqa/)

Hope this helps