# Superscript Placeholder Text HTML

Tags: html, coding-style, superscript

I am trying to superscript a dagger in HTML placeholder text, but it literally shows as: First Name<sup>†</sup>

Does anybody know how I can properly display the superscript? All tips are welcome!

Comment: sorry to better represent how it appears I've added spaces -  it shows as First Name < sup > † < /sup >

Comment: I have to ask, what is the dagger for? What you're specifically asking for can't be done, but I'm curious as maybe there's an alternative.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270820/how-to-use-superscript-in-an-html-text-input-tag  (has some aforementioned alternatives)

Comment: Another one, more inline with what you're specifically trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878812/adding-sup-asterisk-to-placeholder-or-a-nice-way-to-mark-required-fields-via

Comment: The dagger is to indicate a required field.  The dagger specifically needs to be used as a requirement by the legal department.